# Replace variable in string

Tags: string, replace

i am getting below text from a file

root.folder.wms=//$tmpc/INTEGRATION_MESSAGES/WMS

i wanted to replace $tmpc = localhost

The output should be like this
root.folder.wms=//localhost/INTEGRATION_MESSAGES/WMS

i tried but no luck

Comment: what did you try? what was the result?

Comment: Please add your code so we know what did you tried as this seems to be very simple.

Comment: Replace the text using what?

Comment: Any particular language/environment?

Comment: i want script in Perl: below is my script
$replace is contains => root.folder.wms=//$tmpc/INTEGRATION_MESSAGES/WMS
$tmpc = "abcd";
$replace = $replace;
print "\n======>".$replace."\n";
$line =~ s/$find/$replace/ig;
and the final output is root.folder.wms=//$tmpc/INTEGRATION_MESSAGES/WMS it means nothing got changed

Answer (score 0):

```
String st="root.folder.wms=//$tmpc/INTEGRATION_MESSAGES/WMS";

    int temp=0;

          temp=st.indexOf("$");


        String st1= st.substring(0,temp);
        String st2= st.substring(temp+5,st.length());
        System.out.println(st1);
        System.out.println(st2);            
        String st3=st1+"localhost"+st2;
        System.out.println(st3);

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know in which language you got this problem, and what code you have tried, but i have executed the code in javascript, java and c# and got the same(expected) output. if you need you can refer this.

```
//Java script code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function callMe()
{
    str="root.folder.wms=//$tmpc/INTEGRATION_MESSAGES/WMS";
    alert(str);
    var output= str.replace("$tmpc","localhost");
    alert(output);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= output;
} 
</script>
</head>
<body onload="callMe()">

 <h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
 <p id="demo"></p>
 </body>
 </html> 

//java code

public class ReplaceTest{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String str="root.folder.wms=//$tmpc/INTEGRATION_MESSAGES/WMS";
        System.out.println(str.replace("$tmpc","localhost"));
    } 
 }

//C# code
 using System;
 using System.Diagnostics;
 public class ReplaceTest
 {
  public static void Main()
  {
    string str = "root.folder.wms=//$tmpc/INTEGRATION_MESSAGES/WMS";
    Debug.WriteLine(str.Replace("$tmpc", "localhost"));
  }
}
```

Comment: $tmpc = "localhost";
$temp = "root.folder.wms=//$tmpc/INTEGRATION_MESSAGES/WMS";
print "output:".$temp; this out put is perfect.. But the problem is 
i am getting this string "root.folder.wms=//$tmpc/INTEGRATION_MESSAGES/WMS" from a from a file how can i replace $tmpc as local host

Comment: Finally its resolved. after adding this logic
%envs = ("WMS_Machine", "$environment_pc3",
         "TMS_Machine", "$environment_pc2",
         "CURRENT_DATE", "$CURRENT_DATE",
         "DATABASEHOST_AND_SIDNAME", "$TMS_DB_Host_SID");

Comment: Finally its resolved. after adding this logic
%envs = ("WMS_Machine","$environment_pc3","TMS_Machine","$environment_pc2");
my @line_array = split(/=>/, $fine_replace_line);
  $find = trim($line_array[0]);
  $replace = trim($line_array[1]);
  $file = "$Target_filename";
  open (IN,$file) || die;
  @lines=<IN>;
  close IN;
  open (OUT,">", $file) || die;
  foreach $line (@lines) { if ($line =~ $find) {
    foreach $replace_var (keys %envs)
     { $replace =~ s/$replace_var/$envs{$replace_var}/ig; }
     $line =~ s/$find/$replace/ig;
    } print OUT $line;
  }